# Python can't find module to import despite __init__.py files being present

Tags: python, python-unittest

I've looked all over for a day or so and am about ready to pull my hair out. Help me, SO, you're my only hope.

I have found countless solutions to this issue that boil down to "make sure you have __init__.py in appropriate places and it should just work."

I am sure that I am missing something obvious, this is a noob question.

Anyways -

[Folder structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqvTa.png)

I have added what __init__ files I believe should exist.

Here is the code for my unit test:

```
    import unittest
from pyrum.src import Card

class TestCard(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_Card_Initalization(self):
        #Tests that numeric position is set properly for various options.
        self.assertTrue(Card("S","A").position==1)
        self.assertTrue(Card("S","2").position==2)
        self.assertTrue(Card("S","J").position==11)
        self.assertTrue(Card("S","Q").position==12)
        self.assertTrue(Card("S","K").position==13)
        #Tests that an exception is raised when an invalid suit is passed.
        with self.assertRaises(Exception) as context:
            Card("Z","Z")
        self.assertTrue('Suit Z provided does not match recongized suit code. Options are: [S: Spades, H: Hearts, C: Clubs, D: Diamonds]' in str(context.exception))

    def test_attack(self):
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        pass
```

It is under construction, but this is it.

Whatever way I call test_Card.py (have tried a few different ways/contexts), I still get

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/VSCodeDockerTest/pyrum/test/test_Card.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pyrum.src import Card
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrum'
```

But to my understanding, it should be able to find pyrum no problem. When I place the card and test modules in the same folder (and change the import accordingly) it works fine.

Can someone please explain to me what I am missing? I am at my wits end here, and don't know what else I could search or look at to find a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try: `from src import Card`
that could work

Answer (score 1):

Here is my own solution. If someone has a better answer as to what is going on, I am all ears.

From this related Q&A:
[My module has __init__.py and still Python can't import it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39954495/my-module-has-init-py-and-still-python-cant-import-it/39954623)

It seems like the issue was that python doesn't handle paths how I think it does? I was able to fix it by running

```
cd ..
export PYTHONPATH=.
```

and then running

```
python ./pyrum/tests/runner.py
```

(runner.py runs all my tests in turn)

I also removed the __init__.py files from src and test, but I am not sure that that, specifically, was necessary or helpful.

I am curious how to avoid having to do that each time I want to run my tests without permanently modifying my path. I am developing on Docker so I am less concerned if that's the best solution (I can just write a bash script to do those 3 things if I really have to...) but I'd like a clean and portable solution, if anyone has something better. I am assuming using a virtual environment would alleviate some of this issue, so I will probably try that in the future as my next random thing to try.

Now it's working everywhere *except* the debugger.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: How is the literal steps to resolve the issue not the solution to the problem?

Comment: Maybe because of the last part of your answer which seems like a follow-up question. Please remove that part and either edit it to the question or ask a new one... Also *"I immediately found a way to get it to work after posting"* then maybe you should wait before posting? Give yourself a chance to solve the problem. Formulating a question is a good step though. Try to read your own question and solve it again, only if you can't succeed again, post it

Comment: "*I am developing on Docker*" This detail on your answer is not clearly present in your question. YOu might want to edit your question to include/mention that info to improve your [mcve].

Comment: I'm also working on Docker, had the same issue as OP. Running `export PYTHONPATH=.` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

As you are importing `pyrum.src`, you are considering it as a module. Therefore, you have to use [-m option](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m).

Example: if your `pyrum` folder is at `a/b/c/pyrum`, stand on `a/b/c` and call

```
python -m pyrum.test.test_Card  # without .py extension
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't seem to like that. It still throws the same error regardless. That works now from the parent directory of pyrum, but I don't believe it was working until I changed PYTHONPATH.